# how to get bottom to top level category array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]

in this table we create multiple level sub category with using 'parent_category_id' then how to get this type of array using query or php code

**Expected Output :**

i can search category_id=7 and it return bottom to top levev category

in this case 10 is child of 7 and 7 is child of 1

```
Array
(   
   [0] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 1
            [category_name] => Business Cards
        ),
   [1] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 10
            [category_name] => One Sided
        ),
  [2] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 7
            [category_name] => Standard
        )
)
```

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong! 10 is child of 7 and 7 is child of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "select category_id, category_name from category_table where category_id = '$id'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query); //assuming you perform mysqli_connection first

$array_output = array();

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$array_output[] = $row;

while(!empty($row)){
   if($row['parent_category_id'] == 0) break;
   $query = "select category_id, category_name from category_table where category_id = '{$row['parent_category_id']}'";
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
       $array_output[]= $row;
  }
```

Comment: i need top to bottom category

Comment: but how to get end level

Comment: @ShaktiPatel  if parent_category_id is zero it is the most top level. Then  `if($row['parent_category_id'] == 0) break;` will break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = array() ;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $items[(int) $row['category_id']] = array(
    "category_id" => $row['category_id'],
    "category_name" => $row['category_name'] 
  ) ;
}
```

Note that I use `category_id` as index in that array, so it would be extremely easy to search categories by id.

If you still need usual indexing starting from `0`:

```
  $items[] = array(
    "category_id" => $row['category_id'],
    "category_name" => $row['category_name'] 
  ) ;
```

Comment: i need top to bottom category

Comment: What do you mean? Describe the desired result in your question.